# Shall [i3] you from an off-topic tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

<sub>This is the wittiest title I could come up with, sorry</sub>

There's an [i3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/i3) tag which I believe should be burninated for the following reasons:

1. It's a specific software and questions to it are pretty much always off-topic on SO since it's not primarily used for programming.
2. It only has 98 questions, most of which are low in quality and left unanswered.
3. Did I mention that it's off-topic?
4. i3wm has its own support platform on reddit which we specifically chose since questions do not belong on SO.
5. i3 is a very short keyword and gets in the way of (potentially) more useful and on-topic tags such as [i386](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/i386). If anything it should be named [i3wm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/i3wm), but… see the other bullet points.
6. And it's off-topic.

To add some further information, I'm the (co-)maintainer of i3 and would like to get questions through channels we monitor actively in case they do contain weird bugs etc. at some point, so burninating this tag would also serve us. Sort of.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make much sense, I see plenty of programming questions.  Forbidding programmers from tagging their questions with their programming environment is not productive.  User @Adaephon has a large number of answers in the tag.  I pinged him, might be a while before he responds.

Comment: Most of the few programming questions I saw could have done without the i3 tag. And I wonder where *tagging* your environment becomes unproductive: one could tag every question with my OS, window manager, app launcher, editor, terminal, shell, kernel and monitor setup, but it certainly wouldn't be useful. And while the platform might be somewhat relevant, the window manager should almost never be relevant for programming questions.

Comment: Maybe cleanup the tag, then see what is left? I don't support a burninate unless there are 10 or less ok questions.

Comment: @Grant: I scanned the most recent 10 posts and all were off topic. This is not looking good.

Comment: I just closed 60-70 posts almost without trying. There are about 20 left that may be programming related. I’m done for now.

Comment: There are window managers that are configured by modifying a program (e.g. [tag:dwm] and [tag:xmonad]), which makes it more likely for questions about them to be on-topic. That is not the case for i3; accordingly, question appropriateness seems to suffer.

Comment: After further cleanup this morning (retagging, deleting 0 score Posts that’d be roomba’d), the tag consists of 50 closed posts.

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup! So what would be the next step now?

Comment: @IngoBürk: this made it easier for the community to burninate the tag, lets see what happens.

Comment: Lets do it! Take [tag:i3] down!

Comment: @HansPassant I have been summoned? I have no strong feelings towards keeping this tag on Stack Overflow. As noted by Ingo Bürk and shown by Martijn Pieters' "closing spree", most of the questions were indeed off-topic and in retrospect I probably should have flagged the questions as such back then.  Some of them might have been better placed on U&L, SU or maybe askubuntu, where equivalent tags exist.

Comment: i7 the motion to remove

Comment: Maybe it was much less of a problem if the tag was "i3wm"